# How to customize publicURL of images

Tags: gatsby, strapi, gatsby-image

I am using `gatsby` with `gatsby-source-strapi`.

The following `graphql` request returns the `publicURL` of a `Post`.

```
  allStrapiPost {
    nodes {
      image {
        publicURL
      }
    }
  }
```

This url looks like `/static/ad7b2564f1eb5bdf96cb081b3b23967c-eeead0eb0feaed6e8ae436e3a38ad5.jpg` which is quite a bad url.

Is there any chance to modify this url f.e. in [onCreateNode](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/node-apis/#onCreateNode)?

Comment: In what sense is it bad? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Its bad for seo and f.e.nobody wants to download datasheets for specific products with this file name.

Comment: Are you using `gatsby-image` and any related plugins?

Comment: Yes I am using `gatsby-image`.

Comment: In that case the answer is no - you cannot modify image paths. Try sending a PR towards `gatsby-source-strapi`.